# kendogrid customise validation message and style

Tags: angularjs, kendo-grid

Is there a way to customize validation message.
Currently I can see message in form of tooltip.
How can I put messages like this?[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `NgMessage`.

```
  <form name="contactForm">
    <div>
      <input type="text" name="name" ng-model="formData.name" placeholder="Zooly" required />
      <div ng-messages="contactForm.name.$error">
        <div ng-message="required" style="color:red">Name is required</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- <button type="submit">Validate</button> -->
  </form>
```

**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/RKkmBtpObERRWoJEZ59i?p=preview)**

Don't forget to add NgMessage as a dependency of your AngularJS project.

```
angular.module('app', ['ngMessages'])
```